# how do I return an array from fetch using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm taking a JavaScript course and I'm creating my own "challenge". Unfortunately, it takes the teachers days to respond, and I don't have that long. I tried searching for the answer, but I seem to have come up short.

I created a database and pumped the select * results out to a page to simulate an ajax call. I then wrote the following code:

```js
const dataModule = (function() {

  //fetch all data from ajax
  return {
    getData: function() {
      const famData = fetch('http://localhost/Test2/ajaxservers/_test.php')
        .then(result => {
          return result.json()
        });
    }
  }

})();

const uiModule = (function() {

  //some code

})();

const controlModule = (function(data, ui) {

  console.log(data.getData());

})(dataModule, uiModule)
```

as you can see, I'm using the Module pattern. I return a function in the dataModule to fetch the data. the function seems to work OK. if I add a line to it to do `.then(data=> console.log(data));` I see the array returned, but if I call the function from the controlModule without console logging the fetch data, I get undefined. What am I missing?

Comment: (1) Your `getData` function does not have a `return` (2) If you would return `famData`, you would return a promise. This is the best you can do, as it is impossible to return *now* what only becomes available in the *future*. Don't expect to get the data in a synchronous way. Embrace asynchrony.

Comment: that's a good point. I'm not thinking asynchronously. I totally see now why the function call in the controlModule comes back undefined. Now to figure out how to reorganize this.

Comment: (1) `return famData`; (2) prefix `function(data, ui)` with `async`; (3)  prefix `data.getData()` with `await`.

Comment: I see. I end up returning a promise that I can then consume. Would it be a good idea to not use the module setup? seems to just cause hassles.

Comment: You can just do `result = await (await fetch(url)).json()` within an async function.